# how can i test a get method in my controller

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a property in my controller that I would like to test:

```
public List<SelectOption> exampleProperty {
    get {
        //Do something;
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to cover this code in my test class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is direct way, just invoke the property from test method

```
List<SelectOption> temp = obj.method;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to directly test your properties, especially if you use  [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) - a smart pattern for making code efficient and readable.

Here's a list example of this pattern:

```
Integer[] lotteryNumbers {
    get {
        if (lotteryNumbers == null) {
            lotteryNumbers = new Integer[]{};
        }
        return lotteryNumbers;
    }
    set;
}
```

If you wanted full coverage of the pattern (which may be a good idea while you're getting used to it), you would need to do something like the following:

```
static testMethod void lotteryNumberFactoryText() {
    // test the null case
    System.assert(lotteryNumbers.size() == 0);

    Integer[] luckyNumbers = new Integer[]{33,8};
    lotteryNumbers.addAll(luckyNumbers);

    // test the not null case
    System.assert(lotteryNumbers == luckyNumbers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, do you really want to have an attribute named "method"? Seems a helluva confusing. Anyway, to cover the code, just call

```
someObject.get(method);
```

But code coverage should be a side effect of writing good tests - not the goal. You should think about what the code is supposed to do, and write tests to check (i.e. assert) that it is working.

Comment: that's very optimistic :) Thats how I started as well, then when every single deployment starts taking 10 minutes to run all "proper" tests you start changing the strategy and start gunning for the necessary coverage :)

Comment: ha ha.. thats true... Some of the consultants i work for are insistent on getting the max coverage.. Regarding the name as method was an oversight..when i keyed in the code